# Why can't I change the mapbox text colours?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I want to change the colour and what is being plotted using the mapbox API. but I seem to be getting an error and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Following this post so far: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-hover/

here's what I coded up:

```
        map.addLayer({
            id: 'points',
            type: 'symbol',
            source: 'point', // reference the data source
            layout: {
                'text-field': '{hospitalName}',
                'text-font': ['Open Sans Semibold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
                'text-offset': [0, 1],
                'text-anchor': 'top'
            },
            paint: {
                'text-color': '#ffffff',
                'circle-color': '#4264fb',
                'circle-radius': 6,
                'circle-stroke-width': 2,
                'circle-stroke-color': '#ffffff'
            }
        });
```

but here is the error that I am getting:

evented.js:145 Error: layers.points.paint.circle-radius: unknown property "circle-radius"
at Object.Ui [as emitValidationErrors]

I did check elsewhere if my GeoGjsons are compliant are not if that was throwing an error and it seems like that is not an issue:

````
coordinates: (2) [88.3541535, 22.5396878]
type: "Point"
__proto__: Object
properties: {hospitalName: "F-------", icon: "hospital", beds: 0, comment: "----."}
type: "Feature"```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text only works on symbols not circles
Code snippet:

```
map.addLayer({
        id: 'points',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'point', // reference the data source
        layout: {
            'icon-size': 0.05,
            'text-field': '{hospitalName}',
            'text-font': ['Open Sans Semibold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
            'text-offset': [0, 1],
            'text-anchor': 'top',
            'icon-image': ['get', 'icon']
        },
        paint: {
            'text-color': '#ffffff',
        }
    });
```

This seems to work. Why cause circles are categorized as "drawn things" that are not symbols if you wanted to use a circle, In my opinion, the best idea is to make it yourself in illustrator etc and then import it in using an add image functionality. This gives way more flexibility and lets you do much more like text, orientation etc. and in general, I found it easier. Here is the API reference: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/

what you have to look out for is what is the addlayer 'type' in this case it should be a symbol and not points or anything else.

Morover on top you see that I was using a symbol, and the reason I got the error is because a circle is not a symbol and mapbox is then confused. Here is the API reference if you want to draw circles

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'places',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'places',
    'paint': {
        'circle-color': '#4264fb',
        'circle-radius': 6,
        'circle-stroke-width': 2,
        'circle-stroke-color': '#ffffff'
    }
});
```

reference is here: (not the same but the circles bit is an excerpt)
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-hover/

Comment: Please provide code snippet and more information into your answer.